# How do i extend Haskell's type class in my class

Tags: haskell

I want to extend Show type class within my type class and then provide implementation for both of the classes

```
data XX = XX String --class

class Show a => Test a where
    mySh :: a -> String
    show :: a -> String

instance Test XX where --implementation for both show and mySh
    mySh (XX a) = a
    show (XX a) = "---" ++ a
```

I am getting this error

```
    • No instance for (Show XX)
    arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
• In the instance declaration for ‘Test XX’
```

I just want Test to inherit Show (without the default implementation) and provide it's own methods.

Comment: `XX` type isn't showable. Use `data XX = XX String deriving (Show)`

Comment: even if I am overriding show method, should i still use "deriving (Show)"?

Comment: If i use data XX = XX String deriving (Show), I am getting "Ambiguous occurrence ‘show’"

Comment: You shouldn't call your own method `show` as that already exists in the `Show` class. Just choose another name.

Comment: Rereading your question and comments, I think you're coming from an OO background and getting confused. Haskell typeclasses are not that similar to OO classes. In particular you don't "extend" them and you certainly can't "override" methods. If you want to write a custom `show` function for your type then just write an instance: `instance Show XX where... `

Comment: @RobinZigmond - thank you for clarifying this. I got confused because after seeing this line of code in Ord class `class Eq a => Ord a where` I thought it is normal to "extend" classes. Thanks for your help

Comment: Aside, `Show` is meant for debug output, when you want to see the representation of a value as a Haskell expression; `read (show x)` should equal `x`. So in practice, you should almost always use `deriving (Read, Show)`, and for pretty-printing, use a package like [`prettyprinter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter), making instances of its `Pretty` class, using `pretty = viaShow` to reuse the `Show` instance if needed. This offers better performance and also a lot of nice formatting options like indentation & alignment that are inconvenient to do with `Show`/`ShowS`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *subclass relation* `Show a => Test a` (read: `Show` is a superclass of `Test`) simply means that any type which is an instance of `Test` must also be an instance of `Show`, i.e. pretty much exactly what GHC is telling you. To this end, well, write that instance:

```
instance Show XX where
  show (XX a) = "---" ++ a  -- please don't implement it this way, `show`
                            -- is supposed to yield valid Haskell code
instance Test XX where
  mySh (XX a) = a
```

In practice, the `Show` class is almost always best instantiated with a simple `deriving` statement:

```
data XX = XX String
  deriving (Show)

instance Test XX where
    mySh (XX a) = a
```

What you can *not* do in Haskell, is “override” the `show` method. That's something OO languages do to get a different run-time behaviour on a *subtype*, which is basically what an OO child class is. Subtype because it contains values that can also be used as values of the parent class. But Haskell does not have subtypes. You may rather think of classes as *sets of types*, and a subclass of the `Show` class is a subset of the set of types which have a `Show` instance.